# How to implement Bifurcation of delayed Lorenz system?

Tags: plotting, graphics, differential-equations, code-request

The delayed Lorenz system is as follows: (Bifurcation parameter as $\tau$)

$$\begin{align*}
D^\alpha x_1(t) = & a_1(x_2(t-\tau)-x_1(t)) \\  
D^\alpha x_2(t) = & a_2x_1(t)-x_2(t)-x_1(t)x_3(t) \\
D^\alpha x_3(t) = &-a_3x_3(t-\tau)+\frac{1}{2}(x_1(t)x_2(t))
\end{align*}$$

Comment: If you are looking for a numerical solution to this, you to need to specify the values of `a's`? It seems that `\alpha` is a fractional derivative parameter, so again you need to assign a certain value to it.

Comment: a_1=10, a_2=28, a_3=8/3, \alpha=1, That is ordinary delay differential equations.

Comment: This question seems incomplete. It states a system of equations, but does not tell what kind of results are wanted. Please supply more information. Also, give the values for constants in the main post, not in a comment.

Comment: This question was put here last year already once

Answer (score 3):

Well, to be honest, you did not provide any information as also mentioned by @m_goldberg. Any ways, I choose random initial conditions and a random value for the delay `tau = 1`.

```
a1 = 10; a2 = 28; a3 = 8/3; alpha = 1; \[Tau] = 1;

sol = First[
   NDSolve[{x1'[t] == a1*(x2[t - \[Tau]] - x1[t]), 
     x1[t /; t <= 0] == 3,
     x2'[t] == a2*x1[t] - x2[t] - x1[t]*x3[t], x2[t /; t <= 0] == 6,
     x3'[t] == -a3*x3[t - \[Tau]] + 1/2*x1[t]*x2[t], 
     x3[t /; t <= 0] == 3}, {x1, x2, x3}, {t, 0, 20}]];

Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 200}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Note: Next time provide complete information, not just a bunch of equations.**

**Addition** 
(*Space curve for:`{x1[t],x2[t],x3[t]}`*)

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 150}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thickness[0.015]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x1, x2, x3}]
```

Comment: a_1=10, a_2=28, a_3=8/3, \alpha=1, That is ordinary delay Lorenz system. I really want to draw the bifurcation diagram with varying delay parameter (\tau=0.1 to 1.0).